# If a Group control is made invisible does the Container inside it also becomes invisible?

Tags: java, swt, controls

I have a Group Control which contains a Container control which in turn has Text controls. Initially I have this Group hidden and so all the controls inside is hidden. But when I set the group as visible, none of the controls inside it becomes visible. So i was thinking whether my understanding that if we set a control as invisible all the control will be hidden and vice-versa, is correct?

Edit:

```
Group grp= new Group(container, SWT.NONE);
grp.setText("XYZ");
grp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
Conatiner cnt = new Container(grp, SWT.NONE);
cnt.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,true));
cnt.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false));
```

Comment: You need to post code.

Comment: It's not about code. I want to know the concept.

Comment: Why not just check one of the controls visibility property after changing the visibility property of the Group Control?

Comment: Cool let me try that.

Comment: @TheBlindSpring It shows true but the controls are still not visible. I have added my declaration in the question. Let me know if this is correct.

Comment: What is true? Are you making the group box visible or invisible? Are you checking to see if controls are visible or invisible?